# Process fields with nested arrays into strings with strcat_array for output in Kusto

Tags: kql

I would like to process Azure AD audit Logs into HTML tables/csv files. The data contains nested sets of arrays that I would like to summarise into a comma separated string.

eg data that looks like this

```
{
    "TargetResources":  [{"displayName":  "Policy",
                          "modifiedProperties":  [{"displayname":  "PolicySetting1"},
                                                  {"displayname":  "PolicySetting2"}]
                        }]
}
```

Would be processed into

```
TargetResource | Policy
modifedProps   | PolicySetting1, PolicySetting2
```

`mv-expand` doesn't seem to work because some rows do not have modifiedProperties so those rows get eliminated

The only solution I have been able to find that gets close to what I am trying to do looks like this:

```
 AuditLogs
| extend TargetResource = tostring(TargetResources[0].displayName)
| extend ModifiedProperty0 = tostring(parse_json(tostring(TargetResources[0].modifiedProperties))[0].displayName)
| extend ModifiedProperty1 = tostring(parse_json(tostring(TargetResources[0].modifiedProperties))[1].displayName)
| extend ModifiedProperty2 = tostring(parse_json(tostring(TargetResources[0].modifiedProperties))[2].displayName)
| extend ModifiedProperties = strcat(ModifiedProperty0,", ",ModifiedProperty1,", ",ModifiedProperty2)
```

This solution is limited in that it cannot work for arbitrary numbers of modifiedProperty values (it only works properly for exactly 3) which is a requirement for my purposes, I would like the solution to work if modifiedProperties does not exist and if there are 0-15 values.

Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood your description correctly, you could use `mv-apply` (twice) to achieve that:

```
datatable(d: dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"TargetResources":[{"displayName": "Policy0","someOtherProperty":"hello world"}]}),
    dynamic({"TargetResources":[{"displayName": "Policy1","modifiedProperties":[{"displayname":"PolicySetting1"},{"displayname":"PolicySetting2"}]}]}),
    dynamic({"TargetResources":[{"displayName": "Policy2","modifiedProperties":[{"displayname":"PolicySetting3"},{"displayname":"PolicySetting4"}]}, {"displayName":"Policy3","modifiedProperties":[{"displayname":"PolicySetting5"},{"displayname":"PolicySetting6"}]}]}),
]
| mv-apply tr = d.TargetResources on (
    extend TargetResource = tr.displayName
    | mv-apply mp = tr.modifiedProperties on (
        extend propertyName = mp.displayname
        | summarize modifiedProps = strcat_array(make_set(propertyName), ", ")
    )
)
| project TargetResource, modifiedProps
```

| TargetResource | modifiedProps |
| --- | --- |
| Policy0 |  |
| Policy1 | PolicySetting1, PolicySetting2 |
| Policy2 | PolicySetting3, PolicySetting4 |
| Policy3 | PolicySetting5, PolicySetting6 |

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For anyone using this method for my exact purpose, note the case of the displayName attribute for modified properties needs to be updated - this is a mistake in my question, not the answer.